# How do I get SSL certificate from ACM, using android aws sdk?

Tags: android, aws-sdk, aws-certificate-manager

I am trying to retrieve SSL certificate from ACM, but unable to. I tried using the old aws-java-sdk-acm but it has a http client which is no more usable. Hence I am not able to fetch the certificate from the AWS. Please help me out as I dont see any option / acm methods in the latest aws sdk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you mean by "retrieve SSL certificate"? Do you want to pull the certificate with the private key? If so, please refer to John Hanley's answer.

If you just want the public portion of the certificate (what is served from a webserver, etc.), you can call ACM's [GetCertificate](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/APIReference/API_GetCertificate.html) to pull the certificate with chain.

Comment: Thanks for this tip on requestCertificate(). I was not aware of that API.

Comment: Whoops! I misspoke. Meant to say getCertificate.

Comment: Thats funny. I actually looked up the API and did not notice my misspelling in my comment. https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/acm.html#ACM.Client.get_certificate

Answer (score 3):

You cannot download an SSL certificate stored in ACM. The private key is protected. ACM provides FREE SSL certificates for Amazon services and controls where they can be installed and who can create them. If Amazon did not control this, the certificates would be worthless.

That said, ACM can deploy/install your SSL certificate(s) to endpoints managed by the following supported services in your AWS account: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-services.html

Additional Information:

To download the public key using openssl:

```
openssl s_client -connect www.mywebsite.com:443 | openssl x509 -pubkey -noout
```